# PowerMock/JUnit/Guice - Mocking the Private Construction with Injection

Tags: java, junit, powermock

I have a class which is using the GUICE DI and I am trying to write a unit test for this. Here i have two issue, one is the private constructor and 2nd is its injected with parameters. Any help how to write a test case for this. Here is the sample code.

```
public class DataServiceMngr  {

    Utility objUtility;
    Service ObjService;

    @Inject
    private DataServiceMngr(Utility objUtility, Service ObjService) {
        this.objUtility = objUtility;
        this.ObjService = ObjService;
    }

    public String fetchData() {

        return "DATA_FETCHED";
    }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)  
@PrepareForTest({Utility.class, DataServiceMngr.class})  
public class UtilityTest {

    @Test
    public void TestStaticMethod_WithPowerMockito() {  

        String callexpectation = "DATA_FETCHED";  

        DataServiceMngr mgr = PowerMockito.mock(DataServiceMngr.class);
        assertEquals(callexpectation, mgr.fetchData());


    }
}
```

Comment: The simple answer is to follow Java standard practice and not use a private constructor. The only time I've ever seen a nontrivial private constructor is when the class has a nested Builder, in which case you can provide the mocks as builder arguments.

Comment: Thanks Chrylis , I am not using the pvt constructor now and i am good to go